# qt combobox scrollbar behaviour

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qcombobox

Is there any way to change the behaviour of the scrollbar inside qcombobox?
The behaviour is:
position of the scrollbar corresponds to the pointer position of the record in the dataset. While changing the position of the scrollbar the records are added and removed from the combobox.
So it becomes possible to browse the dataset (~1000000 records) but without adding all the records to the combobox (it's very slow after 1000 records).

Answer (score 0):

The standard Qt way of doing this is with a [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractitemmodel.html) to populate the portion of the view that is visible.

That said, I'm not sure you have fully considered the implications of a combobox with 1 million items from a user interface point of view. That many items and your users will have difficulty finding what they are looking for. To make this usable, you would probably need a way of sorting or categorizing entries in a way I don't think QComboBox provides. There must be a better way. That question might be better suited for the guys at http://ux.stackexchange.com, though.

Comment: Thank you for reply,Sean Cline, by the way to many records it is not the matter. The application would consist the several such comboboxes with 90 - 1000000 records that will sort each other up and down hierarchically and in the alphabeticall(with autocompletion) manner too. I'v done such application before in the c++ builder(made my own combobox), but now i'm in the Qt and looking for elegant way to do this.